Formula or VBA script to dynamically duplicate the contents AND formatting of another cell where the original cell formatting is manually changed
I am looking for a way to duplicate the contents and cell formatting of a cell, where the contents of the reference cell is manually entered.  IE:  Sheet1  Cell AX14 contains a text value (manually entered) and a format color (also manually entered), and the same cell in multiple sheets will duplicate BOTH the contents of the mannually entered cell 'Sheet1'!AX14 AND its manually formatted color to 'Sheet2'!AX14 as well as 'Sheet3'!AX14.
There is no formula in the original reference cell to duplicate formatting as it is manually entered. Thanks in advance for the help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use sheet grouping. If the worksheets form a group, whatever you enter manually into one of them is duplicated in the others. Here is a description of how to group sheets
Group worksheets - Microsoft Support
However, in order to move freely between grouped worksheets without disturbing the grouping, there should be at least one additional worksheet in the workbook that does not belong to the group.
In VBA you can use a code like this:
Sub CopyToSheets()
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Sheets(x).FillAcrossSheets _
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX14")
End Sub

In this case you don't need to group sheets before using this code.
